# Address Firebase object by child value, and then modify that object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm facing a little difficulty finding information about how to modify objects in Firebase Realtime Database. I'm adding items into my database in real-time, so I won't know ahead of time what the object key is. As you know, the database structure looks like this:

[image: Screengrab of Firebase data structure]

Say I want to address a child of "testing", whose category is "social", what I do is this:

```
firebase.database().ref("testing").orderByChild("category").equalTo("social")
```

But how exactly can I then address this child so as to update this entire child (including all the fields - "category", "date", etc.) or even delete it? Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

To update (or delete) a node in Firebase you must know the complete path to that node. If you don't know the complete path, you can use a query to determine the node(s) matching a certain condition.

So in your case you'll need to execute the query, loop over the results, and update each child node in turn. In code:

```
let query = firebase.database().ref("testing").orderByChild("category").equalTo("Social");
query.once("value").then((results) => {
  results.forEach((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.ref.update({ propertyToUpdate: "new value" });
  });
});
```

If you want to delete the matching node(s), the innermost line would be: `snapshot.ref.remove()`.